# Find mode in panda Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Find mode among all values in c1_ind   and c2_ind . I don't want to mode along each column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import mode


list =[{"col1":123,"C1_IND    ":"Rev","C2_IND":"Hold"},
{"col1":456,"C1_IND    ":"Hold","C2_IND":"Rev"},
{"col1":123,"C1_IND    ":"Hold","C2_IND":"Service"},
{"col1":1236,"C1_IND    ":"Man","C2_IND":"Man"}]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(list)
print(df)
```

For another example Find mode among all values in c1_ind   and c3_ind

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import mode


list =[{"col1":123,"C1_IND    ":"Rev","C2_IND":"Hold","C3_IND":"Hold"},
{"col1":456,"C1_IND    ":"Hold","C2_IND":"Rev","C3_IND":"Rev"},
{"col1":123,"C1_IND    ":"Hold","C2_IND":"Service","C3_IND":"Service"},
{"col1":1236,"C1_IND    ":"Man","C2_IND":"Man","C3_IND":"Man"}]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(list)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to select the columns of interest (here by regex), then [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and finally use [`mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html).:

```
df.filter(regex='C\d+_IND').stack().mode().iloc[0]
```

*NB. If there are several modes, we only keep one. If you want all, remove the `iloc[0]`, optionally replacing with `squeeze`.*

Output: `'Hold'`

Comment: Incase I received multiple values using squeeze, is there way to convert those values to list ?

Comment: I got it . Thanks `list=v.to_list()
print(list)
`

Comment: `squeeze` will just convert a series to scalar if there is only one item. You might want `df.filter(regex='C\d+_IND').stack().mode().tolist()`

Comment: You have provided better option